# Symbol for m by n matrix

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I have been using `m \times n` to denote the size of a matrix. But lately I've decided that it has too much space and doesn't look quite right (to me). Presumably the largish spaces are present because LaTeX treats `\times` as a mathematical operator -- it thinks I'm writing `$m$` multiplied by `$n$`.

So, I'd like to define a `\by` symbol, so that I can write `m \by n` instead of `m \times n`, and get reduced spacing. The obvious approach is to define `\by` to be `\hspace{-0.1em}\times\hspace{-0.1em}`, or something like that.

Does that seem like a good approach? I'm a bit worried about what will happen if I use this in superscripts.

**Edit:**  I ended up using

```
\newcommand{\by}{\hspace{0.05em}{\times}\hspace{0.05em}}
```

Comment: do you want the result of `$m{\times}n$` or is that too tight?

Comment: Looks pretty good. Because the "times" glyph has some space built into it, I suppose. That was easy. Thanks again.

Comment: @bubba, you edited over my edited.

Comment: @bubba, now I edited again. If you wish, please, change but be careful.

Comment: @bubba, Mathjax does not work here, because we really want to see the code.

Comment: `\newcommand*\by{{\times}}` would be the nice approach that david suggested and then use `$m \by n$`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use `$m{\times}n$` so that you get `mathord` spacing (i.e. no extra space) rather than the default `mathbin` spacing,